# How do I send data from an iPhone via Bluetooth to a MacBook?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

Since you can't send data via Bluetooth from an iPhone to a MacBook, I need to know if there exist any external bluetooth alternatives that you can use to transmit data to a MacBook?

Comment: Does it have to be Bluetooth? What about Wifi?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a jailbroken iPhone, you can send files over Bluetooth using the tweak AirBlue Sharing - here's [the developer's page about it](http://www.if0rce.com/en/airblue-sharing-2/) and [a Lifehacker post about it](http://lifehacker.com/5884586/airblue-sharing-transfers-files-over-bluetooth-on-jailbroken-iphones).